# How to alert hashtag after clicking an anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

I am trying to alert a `#` tag on click of an anchor which produces the `#` tag.
But I only get an alert after a page refresh:

The anchor:

```
$folderanchor = "<a class='folderanchor' href='#".$dir.'/'.$file."'>$file</a>"; 
echo $folderanchor;
```

Reading the `#`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
     if(window.location.hash) {
          var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
          alert (hash);
          // hash found
      } else {
          // No hash found
      }
});
```

The alert should appear immediately after clicking the anchor. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A click on an anchor link does not necessarily reload the page. You might want to use an event for this.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(yourFunction);
```

This sets a click event on all anchor links.

Put the code you have, without the document ready part, in the function (yourFunction).

Answer (score -1):

add +

> href='# + ".$dir.'/'.$file."'